# Ionic get call not working in real android device (no error in console too)

Tags: android, http, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am on ionic 4. And I am using httpClient package to make the http calls. Nothing is happening when I hit the function. And I am not getting error in console too.

I know there are many answers for the same issue, but none of them worked for me.

I am importing as `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';`

My http service as below

```
this.http.get(fullurl)
        .map(data => {
          this.loading.dismiss();
          console.log(data);
          if(msg!="" && msg.length >= 0){
            this.loading.dismiss();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `httpClient.get` is an Observable. Which means you have to use like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 this.http.get(fullUrl)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    // Success handler
  }, (error) => {
    // Error handler
  });
```

Comment: But I do not see subscribe function on get function. Only options I see are 'map' and 'takeUntil'

Comment: Are you sure that you have `private http: HttpClient` on constructor? If yes, which version of `@angular/common` you are using?

Comment: Yes I have it in my constructor. And my angluar/common is 5.2.10. Below is my dependency list

` "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
   "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",
    "cordova.plugins.diagnostic": "^4.0.8",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
 `

Comment: Apparently you are using Ionic 3 `ionic-angular": "3.9.2`. Try using that: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/